# Everytime I do a "git status" it tells me that I have modified about 800 files that I haven't touched at all

Tags: android, git

All I am doing is editing a single class in my Android project, and then when I do git status, git tells me that I have made changes to a whole bunch of files that I have not changed at all. Any solutions?

Comment: Can you be more specific about the files your talking about? There are a lot more files to a project then just the files you are actively developing in. For example IDE specific project files, generated source, build or resource files etc. That there are changes to more files then you actually edited is not strange at all, in fact it is the norm.

Comment: I'm using android studio. the files that keep showing up as modified are appcompat, .gradle, .idea, and some random other ones

Comment: Sounds completely normal to me.

Comment: If you don't already have a proper `.gitignore` file you might want to create one and for starters ignore all files contained in the `build` folder of each of your modules. That should cut down on the modified files considerably. Anything inside the `build` folder shouldn't be under version control anyway.

Comment: Would you possibly want to do a Join.me so you can see my screen and perhaps we can figure this out?

Comment: No I can't do that right now, but I am telling you: this is completely normal. Have you ever checked the amount of files you have in a project? There are literally thousands and your source code only makes up a tiny portion of that. Don't worry about it, you are just waisting your time.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the extension of the files inside .gitignore file. This will
be in your main build directory. If this is not present, you can create one.
Below is the example format  for this.

```
zzzz.*
*~
\#*
*.dll
*.exe
*.exp
*.lib
*.local
*.log
*.man
*.nbattrs
*.ncb
*.obj
*.pdb
*.res
```

Comment: I did that, but still when I do git status even though I only modified 1 file, it tells me that I have modified 500 files. 
I haven't added the 2 things you just added, let me try. Yeah, it still says I modified a whole bunch of files =/.

Comment: I added filemode and now i'm getting this error "fatal: bad numeric config value 'true       bare = false' for 'core.filemode' in .git/config: invalid unit"

Comment: Would you want to do a join.me and see if you can figure it out?

Comment: Where do I actually find the .gitignore file?

Comment: you may add one by yourself in the main build directory.

Answer (score 0):

Before modifying your file do git pull. Once its updated then you start modifying your file and you will be able to do git push.

Comment: So I did this. I got the "On branch master Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'." message. Then I added one line of code in one class, and did a git status and it says that I modified 2 extra files

Comment: compare the modified file and you can find the difference. According to that update it.